# selenium can't find element even though it exists

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a submit button like this:

`sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@type='submit' and @class='btn-primary']")))`

but I get an error says can't find the element but actually it exists

this is the source code of page:

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="my_login_phone">Your Phone Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-large" id="my_login_phone" placeholder="+12223334455" autocomplete="off"/>
              <p class="help-block">Please enter your number in <a href="https://telegram.org/faq#login-and-sms" target="_blank">international format</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="support_submit">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Next</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <form method="POST" action="/auth/login" class="hide" id="my_login_form" onsubmit="return checkPassword(event);">
            <input type="hidden" id="my_login_phone_input" name="phone">
            <input type="hidden" id="my_random_hash" name="random_hash">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Your Phone Number</label>
              <span class="form-control input input-large uneditable-input"><strong id="my_login_phone_field"></strong> (<a href="/auth">Incorrect?</a>)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="my_password">Confirmation code</label>
              <input type="text" id="my_password" class="form-control input-large" name="password" placeholder="Confirmation code">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="support_submit">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign In</button>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

what should I do?

I tried to find an element with selenium

Comment: Maybe it's because the class is `"btn btn-primary btn-lg"`, not `"btn-primary"`?